# Vk Api надо достать изображеник из сообщения

Tags: php, python, vkontakte-api

У меня есть бот которой должен запоминать изображение присланную в беседу и по команде отправить ее. Но я запоминаю от изображения OwnerId и MediaId(то что нужно чтобы получилось photo7162616_737) но когда я добавляю это изображение к attachment'у то он просто его не добавляет, слышал что бот не имеет доступа к фото из бесед, но как бы вы это реализовали?

Сохранение ссылок на изображение тоже не робит.

Answer (score 0):

Если фото выкладывается сообществом, то не забудте добавить знак "-" перед id, в вашем случае **photo-7162616_737**. Так же стоит проверить есть ли доступ у бота к фотографиями (проверьте в настройках вашей группы. Если же ваш бот работает от имени пользователя, тогда проблем быть не должно.